# I am not sure where is wrong in python code to find duplicate strings

Tags: python

This code is to find out how many times the B string is repeated in the A string. Could you please let me know what went wrong?
I want to type some string A.

If you just type one letter at a time, you will have to press the key for the length of A.

To speed it up a bit, some string B is stored, so you can type the entire B by pressing the key once.

It is not possible to erase already typed characters.

For example, when A = ”asakusa”, B = ”sa”, you can type A in 5 times by using B twice as shown in the following figure.

Given A and B, find the minimum number of times you have to press the key to type A in its entirety.

The first line is given the number T of test cases.

For each test case, two strings A and B are given on the first line. The length of A is 1 to 10,000, and the length of B is 1 to 100.

input

1

apple ap

output

1 4

```py
T = int(input())
for tc in range(1, T + 1):
    A, B = input().split()
    idx = 0
    cnt = 0
    N = len(A)
    M = len(B)
    for i in range(N):
        if A[i] == B[idx]:
            idx += 1
            if idx == len(B):
                cnt += 1
                idx = 0
            else:
                continue
        else:
            idx = 0

    print("#{} {}".format(tc, N - M * cnt + cnt))
```

Comment: What happens when you run the code? What inputs have you used and what output do you get?

Comment: Where does it go wrong? share a case where the output goes wrong

Comment: the `else: continue` is useless in this case

Comment: For example, if 'banana' and 'na' are given as input, 'na' is entered twice in 'banana'. So the answer is 2.

Comment: Could you provide an output of the current code, that would help alot.

Comment: Sorry. The original post has been revised for more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find out how many times the substring B appears in A, at the end you just need to print cnt, i.e.:

```
print("#{} {}".format(tc, cnt))
```